# Embed Ruby code within Slim's HTML attribute

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I'm trying to generate a series of progress bars with random completion width, using the lovely [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/) templating language.

This is the code I would like to generate:

```rb
.progress-info
  .progress
    span.progress-bar.progress-bar-success data-toggle='tooltip' style="width: 20%;"
```

However I would like to generate the style's width randomly, something like:

```rb
.progress-info
  .progress
    span.progress-bar.progress-bar-success data-toggle='tooltip' style="width: #{rand(50)+'%'};"
```

Of course this does not work, it's just to give an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with `rand(50)+'%'` – you’re trying to add a String (`'%'`) to a Fixnum (the result of `rand`).

You can fix it with a call to `to_s`:

```
span.progress-bar.progress-bar-success data-toggle='tooltip' style="width: #{rand(50).to_s + '%'};"
```

or more simply by only including the call to `rand` in the interpolation:

```
span.progress-bar.progress-bar-success data-toggle='tooltip' style="width: #{rand(50)}%;"
```